# Alternate method for this nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.assignment_id, 
        t.timesheet_id, 
        t.hours, 
        (SELECT SUM(tss.hours) FROM timesheets tss 
               WHERE tss.assignment_id = t.assignment_id) as 'sumhours'
FROM timesheets t
```

which yields:

```
assignment_id  |  timesheet_id  |   hours  |  sumhours
---------------------------------------------------------
      2               2              4.50         8.00
      2               3              3.50         8.00
      3               4              0.00         0.00
      3               5              0.00         0.00
```

Table Definitions:

```
'timesheets' (
      'timesheet_id' int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      'hours' decimal(10,2),
      'assignment_id' int(11),
       PRIMARY KEY ('timesheet_id'),
       CONSTRAINT 'assignment_fk' FOREIGN KEY ('assignment_id') REFERENCES 'assignments' ('assignment_id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

So you can see that I am trying to display the number of hours recorded on each timesheet next to the total number of hours for each assignment. One assignment can have many timesheets. Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: If you are interested to know how this could be achieved using WINDOW FUNCTIONS (not applicable to MySQL, but most other modern RDBMSs have it) let us know. The SQL statement will look much nicer. EDIT: BTW, it will be just FYI, MySQL do not support it

Comment: I am stuck with using MySQL for now :/

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Correlated subqueries are nearly always less efficient than their uncorrelated equivalents.

Comment: @Strawberry the tables/query were so trivial I didn't think it would be necessary, but I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use of hours in your results here?
If you need just the sum, you can do:

```
SELECT t.assignment_id, 
       t.timesheet_id, 
       SUM(t.hours)
FROM timesheets t
GROUP BY t.assignment_id, t.timesheet_id
```

Comment: Since this groups by timesheet_id, it won't sum up all timesheet hours per assignment_id.

Comment: Did you read the question? *So you can see that I am trying to display the number of hours recorded on each timesheet next to the total number of hours for each assignment.*.....and @RonSmith is right, this does not SUM the hours for assignments

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I can't think of a better way to do this then.